# Traverse through multiple addedNodes by MutationObserver and get target.innerText

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, mutation-observers

I am working on a Page where multiple nodes are added per second as well as multiple nodes are removed. But I am interested only about the newly added nodes and the text inside them. here is my script

```
let mList = document.querySelector('._24tx'),
  options = {
    childList: true,
    attributes: false,
    characterData: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributeOldValue: false,
    characterDataOldValue: true
  },
  observer = new MutationObserver(mCallback);

function mCallback(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
      if (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
          if (mutation.target.innerText != '') {
            console.log(mutation.target.innerText);       
          }
        }
      }
    }
  );
}

observer.observe(mList, options);
```

I am getting duplicate entries for single node. How to target each addedNodes and get their innerText?

Comment: You already "target each addedNodes" and "get their innerText" so I guess the problem is how to avoid getting duplicates? It can be because you have `characterData:true`. Anyway, you can store a list of processed nodes in some array inside mCallback, and check if the current node is already there so you'll skip it.

Comment: You have both `characterData: true` and `characterDataOldValue: true`, thus two mutations for each change in character data. Check `mutation.type`.

Comment: how to get only the target where target is only div not any div with class or span?

Comment: 1) It's unclear what "only div not any div with class or span" means. You can check the element's tagName, className, classList, there are lots of examples. 2) The `for` loop in your code is meaningless currently so either remove it or use it properly e.g. check each item of addedNodes for something.